# Process JWT token using JWKs Endpoint

Tags: jwt, jose4j

I receive two JWTs: an OpenID Connect ID token (id_token) and an Access Token (access_token). The situation with OpenID is more or less clear - I can validate it using a JWKS Endpoint: https://smth.com/JWKS.

as in example (https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples):

```
HttpsJwks httpsJkws = new HttpsJwks("https://smth.com/JWKS");
HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver httpsJwksKeyResolver = new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJkws);
jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
    .setVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJwksKeyResolver)
    .setExpectedAudience(...)
    .setExpectedIssuer(...)
    .build();
```

The question is how to proceed with the Access Token. I can extract from it the userId and userDetails, but I guess I need also to validate it?

If I try to validate the Access Token the same as for the ID Token, I am getting this error:

> UnresolvableKeyException: Unable to find a suitable verification key for JWS w/ header {"alg" : "RS256", "kid":"1"}

And indeed there is no key for `"kid" : "1"`, Also this value `"1"` seems kind of strange?

Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: What's the content of https://smth.com/JWKS? smth.com doesn't resolve for me.

Comment: The full exception message should also show the content from that JWKS endpoint. Without seeing the JWKS I can't say exactly what's going on but basically what is happening is the JWT was signed with RSA and a key id header with value "1" was included, which should point to the appropriate verification key in the JWKS (visual example http://www.slideshare.net/briandavidcampbell/i-left-my-jwt-in-san-jose/30). It would appear that there's no RSA key with kid=1 at that JWKS endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for response, I changed question. Yes there is no key for kid=1, also value '1' seems strange compared to OpenID, where I get some real kid, like 'dp1kr' and it changes over time. If you faced this kind of authentication and can give me a hint - if both tokens should be proceeded in same way or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are implementing the role of OpenID Connect client or Relying Party. The two tokens, ID token and access token, serve different purposes and should be handled differently by the client. The ID token is intended for the client and enables authentication of the end-user at the client. The client must validate the ID token (verify the signature and validate claims like exp and aud, etc.) before allowing the end-user in. The access token, however, is for the client to use to access resources or APIs but is not directly intended for the client to consume or validate. The access token is opaque to the client and the client shouldn't care or know about its details. In fact, access tokens aren't always JWTs. In OpenID Connect, the access token is used to call the user info endpoint (with the HTTP header, `Authorization: Bearer [access token]`) to get more claims/info about the end-user.

The value of "1" for the kid is totally legal but it is referring to a key that the AS/OP and the user info endpoint know about somehow. It is not a key at the OpenID Connect JWKS endpoint. "1" isn't a key that the client needs to know about because the client isn't supposed to directly verify the access token.

Comment: I would like to see some confirmation (some link to nice docs i.e.). I cannot find anything about this exact authentication - i mean with too JWT tokens: OpenId and AccessToken.

Comment: Take a look at section 2.2, 2.3, etc. in http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html (which is a simplified profile of http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html but should convey the idea).

Comment: Yes, I read this more or less. But I am still confused that I receive AccessToken as xxx.yyy.zzz and do not use zzz at all. Why then it is there?

Comment: Access tokens [are opaque to the client](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4) and can have different structures and formats. The client shouldn't know or care about the structure of an access token - it just need to know how to use it. In some cases (like your seeing) JWT/JWS is used for the access token. It's to protect it from modification but the RS (userinfo endpoint or other protected resource) needs to verify the signature rather than the client.

Comment: ok, i think this is alredy too much for this question. I probably need to name it correctly and reformulate.